# Style doesn't load after remove public from url in Laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I'm adding a `.htaccess` file in my project root. After adding this `.htaccess` file i can remove the `public` from my `url` but style and js file doesn't load now.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

 RewriteEngine On
# Prevent direct access to the "public" folder - redirect to root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /public/
RewriteRule ^public/(.*) / [R=302,L]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
# - but look for the file in the "public" folder
# (ensure we are not already in the "public" folder)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/ !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ / [R=302,L]

# Rewrite "everything" to the "public" subdirectory if not already
# This ignores existing files/dirs in the document root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)
RewriteRule !^public/ public/%1

# Handle Front Controller... (as before)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How could i load CSS and js from `.htaccess` file